# Right-hand radius edge of button cut off in TableView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a button with a custom background drawable which has round corners. Looks fine normally, but when it appears in a `TableLayout` the right hand edge of the button is getting cut off.

Here's a relevant snippet of the layout XML which places the button in the table layout:

```
    <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/rounded_box_nopadding" android:stretchColumns="1" android:shrinkColumns="1">
        <TableRow android:padding="10dp">
            <TextView android:text="@string/sign_in_email_label" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#000000" android:paddingRight="10dp" />
            <TextView android:text="@string/sign_in_email_hint" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_height="1dp">
            <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1dp" android:background="#dbe3e4" android:layout_span="2" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:padding="10dp">
            <TextView android:text="@string/sign_in_password_label" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#000000" android:paddingRight="10dp" />
            <TextView android:text="@string/sign_in_password_hint" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_height="1dp">
            <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1dp" android:background="#dbe3e4" android:layout_span="2" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:padding="10dp">
            <Button android:id="@+id/my_scoopons_sign_in_button" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/sign_in_button_label" android:textColor="@color/button_text_states" 
                android:textSize="20sp" android:textStyle="bold" android:shadowColor="#671610" android:shadowDy="-2" android:shadowRadius="1" android:background="@drawable/button_states"
                android:layout_span="2"/>
            </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

And here's a screen shot illustrating the problem.

[Android screenshot http://www.petrocky.com/images/device.png](http://www.petrocky.com/images/device.png)

Comment: Just fixed it, simply removed the padding off the `<TableRow>` element and added margin to the `<Button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to fix this by removing the padding off the `<TableRow>` element and added margin to the `<Button>`; i.e.:

```
<TableRow>
    <Button android:id="@+id/sign_in_button" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/sign_in_button_label"  
        android:background="@drawable/button_states"
        android:layout_span="2" android:layout_margin="10dp" />
</TableRow>
```

Because the button is inside the table, it has a width of `fill_parent`. The width of the parent cell is calculated to include the padding, but when rendered it appears too long. By using margin on the button, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The `android:layout_width` is missing from that Button code. Might be the cause.

Comment: No, that's not it. Because the button appears within a table row it doesn't need the `android:layout_width` attribute - it automatically has a width of `fill_parent`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in button layout_span and also not having width of button

You have to set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and i think delete `android:layout_span="2"`
I have modified your code.

hi Mick,

Try with the following code.

```
    <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/rounded_box_nopadding" android:stretchColumns="1" android:shrinkColumns="1">
    <TableRow android:padding="10dp">
        <TextView android:text="@string/sign_in_email_label" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#000000" android:paddingRight="10dp" />
        <TextView android:text="@string/sign_in_email_hint" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_height="1dp">
        <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1dp" android:background="#dbe3e4" android:layout_span="2" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:padding="10dp">
        <TextView android:text="@string/sign_in_password_label" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#000000" android:paddingRight="10dp" />
        <TextView android:text="@string/sign_in_password_hint" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_height="1dp">
        <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1dp" android:background="#dbe3e4" android:layout_span="2" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:padding="10dp">
        <Button android:id="@+id/my_scoopons_sign_in_button" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/sign_in_button_label" android:textColor="@color/button_text_states" 
            android:textSize="20sp" android:textStyle="bold" android:shadowColor="#671610" android:shadowDy="-2" android:shadowRadius="1" android:background="@drawable/button_states"
            />
        </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: No, the button is supposed to have `android:layout_span="2"` because I want the button to span over 2 columns. Also, you don't need to specify height in a view that is inside a table row.